# Formula in Excel using NPOI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, npoi

I am using NPOI for generating Excel spreadsheet in C#. When I apply formula on some cell programmatically and export to Excel then in protected mode of excel sheet all the cells having formula show  '0' value. But when I edit this spreadsheet all formulas work properly on those cells.

Is there any solution from which applied formula can work in protected mode also?

Comment: This is going to sound silly, but have you tried pressing F9 when you have the exported file open in Excel?

Comment: Ann, I know its silly but its happing with each exported file, user are not able to view formula data until they convert excel from protected view to edit mode.

Answer (score 13):

You have to evaluate formulas after setting them:

```
cell = row.CreateCell(j++);
cell.SetCellType(CellType.FORMULA);
cell.SetCellFormula(String.Format("$B$1*B{0}/$B$2*C{0}", i));
cell.CellStyle = styleCell;

if(wb is XSSFWorkbook) {
    XSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
} else {
    HSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
}
```